# Suggestions required for C++ static code analyzer

Tags: c++, code-analysis

Could you suggest any C++ static code analyzer (free version)? Currently we do not use any. I want our team to start using one, before sending the code for review.

Comment: Questions about software recommendations are explicitly off-topic on Stack Overflow, because they attract too much discussion. There exists [softwarerecs.se], but they have strict rules on what should a question contain - if you decide to ask there, check them out beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio comes with its own analyzer, built-in. Also, clang-tidy is a very popular analyzer that Visual Studio 2019 has started shipping with, and is available on any platform you probably care about. You may be aware, though, that integrating any analyzer into a workflow is an enormous task.